# When I click the button to open this activity it closes

Tags: java, android

The main activity has buttons to open new activities for various things. One activity, a calculator, closes as soon as I click the button. The other activities work fine.

The xml file for the activity is question is:

```
<AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/widget0" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="ADDITION OF NUMBERS" 
 android:id="@+id/textView1" 
 android:layout_x="73dip"
 android:layout_y="28dip"></TextView>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_x="36dip" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="First Amount"
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_y="80dip"></TextView>

<EditText android:text=""
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_x="172dip" 
android:id="@+id/amount1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_y="62dip"></EditText>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Second Amount" 
android:id="@+id/textView3" 
android:layout_x="36dip" 
android:layout_y="169dip"></TextView>

<EditText android:text="" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_x="169dip" 
android:id="@+id/amount2" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_y="152dip"></EditText>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/calculate" 
android:layout_x="41dip" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Calculate" 
android:layout_y="232dip"></Button>

<EditText android:text="" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_x="172dip" 
android:id="@+id/tt" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_y="232dip"></EditText>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The java file is:

```
package com.example.welderhelper;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;


public class Calculators extends ActionBarActivity
{
  EditText amount1;
  EditText amount2;
  TextView tt;
  Button calculate;
  double x=0;
  double y=0;
  double z=0;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculators);
      initControls();
  }
  private void initControls()
  {
      amount1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount1);
      amount2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount2);
      tt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tt);
      calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
      calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
      {public void onClick
      (View  v) { calculate();}});
  }
  private void calculate()
  {
      x=Double.parseDouble(amount1.getText().toString());
      y=Double.parseDouble(amount2.getText().toString());
      z=x+y;
      tt.setText(Double.toString(z));
  }
}
```

I was trying to use as a reference, http://www.techillumination.in/2010/02/simple-android-application-for-adding.html, but it didn't work. So even after I copied and pasted it, changing the activity names, it still didn't work. I am learning so I am lost. It is just suppose to take 2 numbers and add them together. Thanks for any help.

Edit: Here is the logcat:

```
04-06 19:35:50.286: V/Activity(4144): onPause  com.example.welderhelper.MainActivity@4204ef40
04-06 19:35:50.306: V/Activity(4144): onCreate  com.example.welderhelper.Calculators@42346760: null
04-06 19:35:50.336: D/AndroidRuntime(4144): Shutting down VM
04-06 19:35:50.336: W/dalvikvm(4144): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41dd0700)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.welderhelper/com.example.welderhelper.Calculators}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at com.example.welderhelper.Calculators.initControls(Calculators.java:34)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at com.example.welderhelper.Calculators.onCreate(Calculators.java:26)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2294)
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     ... 11 more
04-06 19:35:51.527: I/Process(4144): Sending signal. PID: 4144 SIG: 9
```

Comment: And... the logcat... the error... ?

Comment: I just get your layout file and implement initControls() method. It is work fine for me. Clean and build. Then check the spellings. It is NullPointerException, that means the button called :calculate  not initialize correctly when it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From these two lines in your logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 19:35:50.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): at com.example.welderhelper.Calculators.initControls(Calculators.java:34)
```

something is `null` on line 34 in `initControls()` which appears to be this line

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
```

which means you don't have a `Button` in `activity_calculators.xml` with the `id` of `calculate`. It appears that the xml you have posted is for your first `Activity` and not the one you have posted since none of those `id`s from the java file exist in the xml you posted. The `id`s you try to reference should be in `activity_calculators.xml`.

**Edit**

Ok, I really need to pay more attention. Those `id`s are in the xml you posted so either that is not `activity_calculators.xml` or you need to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: The xml I posted was fragment_calculators.xml. That is where I have been putting all the code for all of the activities, fragment_....xml. I also did the clean and rebuild and it didn't work.

Comment: You should have included that in your post. Are you using a fragment here?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes this xml file is fragment_calculators.xml. The java file is Calculators.java

Comment: Ok, then you need `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_calculators)` instead of the xml you have in `setContentView()` currently.

Comment: No problem. You also should take the advice from another answer and use try/catch around your parsings

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your app crashes after pushing the Button labeled Calculate, it's probably because one of the `parseDouble()` method calls is throwing a `NumberFormatException`. Change your `calculate()` method like so:

```
private void calculate()
{
    try
    {
        x = Double.parseDouble(amount1.getText().toString());
        y = Double.parseDouble(amount2.getText().toString()); 
        z = x + y; 
        tt.setText(Double.toString(z));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        tt.setText("Invalid input");
    } 
}
```

Comment: The app closes after you click the button to open this activity from the main activity, but it only started after I added this code. All of the other buttons on the main activity work. I tried your code and it still closed. Thank you.

Comment: Right, I just saw the logcat you posted. It looks like your Button `calculate` is null. Make sure it's in your layout xml file correctly, i.e. with the exact id you have in the code.

Comment: I think you just need to clean and rebuild your project. I just copied/pasted your code and it works as is.

Comment: To clean, I click Project > Clean? I have done that and it didn't work.

Comment: From your comments, it sounds like you're getting Fragments and Activities mixed up. The xml you posted should be in `activity_calculators.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View  v){
        calculate();
    }
});
```

to

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View  v){
        calculate();
    }
});
```

Comment: Same result, app has stopped.